# How do I connect to an SSH server using a TLS bastion?

Tags: go, ssl, ssh

I am trying to connect to an SSH server via a TLS bastion. To connection, I'd normally use the following:

```
ssh 
-o ProxyCommand="openssl s_client -quiet -connect dashed-host:22 -servername dashed-host-local 2>/dev/null" 
username@dashed-host
```

However, I am unsure how to do this in go using the `ssh` and `tls` packages:

I first create the TLS connection, then am I to try to write to it or what do I do?

```
// connect to the bastion host
    bClient, err := tls.Dial("tcp", bastionAddr(deployment), &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to connect to bastion: " + err.Error())
    }

    // What do I do here?
```

I've made some progress:

```
// connect to the bastion host
    bastionServerName := serviceAddr(deployment)
    bClient, err := tls.Dial("tcp", bastionAddr(deployment), &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true, ServerName: bastionServerName})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to connect to bastion: " + err.Error())
    }
    
    // Dial a connection to the service host, from the bastion
    bastionConnection, bChan, bReq, err := ssh.NewClientConn(bClient.NetConn(), serviceAddr(deployment), config)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Bastion connection error: " + err.Error())
    }
```

However, the last bastion creation, `bastionConnection` fails with `ssh: overflow reading version string`; it looks like there's a failure to exchange version strings.

I suspect, by reusing the connection, the TLS session is corrupted?

Thanks